# How to setup an outlook rule on a remote machine(s)

Tags: windows, email, exchange, outlook

I need to setup a custom Outlook 2007 rule and push it to a system(s) without user interaction. I do NOT have access to the Exchange server. How would I do this? Reg key?

Thanks,
-Mathew

Comment: If this can be done, will it also work for earlier versions?

Comment: How many users and can you access their mailboxes (i.e. Login as them?)

Comment: I cannot log in as them.

Comment: what do you mean by "filter"? Do you mean an Outlook rule?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Outlook rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook rules used to be housed on the client running Outlook in earlier versions of Outlook in a file known as a .rwz file. As of Outlook 2007 these are no longer used as they are now stored on the server instead. However the only way I know of would require the user to do an import of the .rwz file, which then copies the settings up to the server. So to answer without interaction there is no way of doing this that I know of.

The .RWZ file would indeed exist if it was migrated from another machine or the software was upgraded from another version of Outlook.

As far as getting it to another machine that could be done a myriad of ways, but would still require user intervention to import the .rwz

Comment: I want to give you as much credit as possible since you pointed out the .rwz file which does exist and work in 2007. I just need to know how to get it on a remote machine.

Comment: Not entirely correct. At least prior to 2007 (which I can't answer for) rules could be either on the client or on the server, depending on the actions specified in the rule.

Comment: The question was for Outlook 2007, which stores on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it properly.

Comment: It can be imported on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web access (webmail) will allow you to login as that user and set up a rule on the Exchange server. :)

Comment: This is absolutely correct!  I have done this in the past and it worked like a champ.  This is also a useful method for setting up mail forwarding without user interaction or getting on the server.

Comment: He can't log in as them

Comment: What I'm curious about is what is he trying to accomplish?

Maybe if he shed some light on the what instead of the how we could offer an alternative to rules altogether?

If it's just some executive who can't be bothered to set aside 3 minutes to get help setting up his rules, who cares? :P

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. In M365 Admin Center, I gave my account the `Exchange Administrator` role and myself `Read and manage permissions` under the user's `Mail` tab. Log into outlook.com/owa and click my name in the top-right > `Open another mailbox`. Got `500 Something went wrong. You don't have permission to perform this action.` Did I have to wait 3 hours first for permissions to propagate or something?

Answer (score 0):

use the OCT (office customisation tool) to deploy Outlook 2007.